# how to use $subtract in $group in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I have below mongo record in purchase table with individual quantity

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60f0a8fa7f73e1b4883e2b26"),
    "status" : "Sold",
    "isSold" : true,
    "unitcost" : 4.5,
    "mrp" : 220,
    "unitprice" : 6,
    "product" : ObjectId("60f0a7c8355781b277607f19"),
    "manufacturingdate" : ISODate("2021-06-30T18:30:00.000Z"),
    "expirydate" : ISODate("2021-07-29T18:30:00.000Z"),
    "customer" : ObjectId("60f0975a93ba0ba2152a1ec0")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60f0a8fa7f73e1b4883e2b87"),
    "status" : "Sold",
    "isSold" : true,
    "unitcost" : 4.5,
    "mrp" : 220,
    "unitprice" : 6,
    "product" : ObjectId("60f0a7c8355781b277607f19"),
    "manufacturingdate" : ISODate("2021-06-30T18:30:00.000Z"),
    "expirydate" : ISODate("2021-07-29T18:30:00.000Z"),
    "customer" : ObjectId("60f0975a93ba0ba2152a1ec0")
}
```

Want data like below Product and customer from there collection and group by product

```
{
 "productDetails":{
          "_id":ObjectId("60f0a7c8355781b277607f19"),
          "title":"Prodcut 1"  
  },
  "profit":3.0,
  "unitprice":6,
  "unitcost":4.5,
  "customerDetails":{
      "_id": ObjectId("60f0975a93ba0ba2152a1ec0"),
     "title":"User 1"  
      }     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

pls refer to Sample code below and also find it here https://mongoplayground.net/p/S9xbt9Lnk5d :

```
db.purchase.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "profit": {
        "$subtract": [
          "$unitprice",
          "$unitcost"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$product",
      "profit": {
        "$sum": "$profit"
      },
      "unitprice": {
        "$first": "$unitprice"
      },
      "unitcost": {
        "$first": "$unitcost"
      },
      "customerDetails": {
        "$push": {
          _id: "$_id"
        }
      },
      
    }
  }
])
```